# Spring Security : How to rename the "_spring_security_remember_me" checkbox field?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

In a Spring MVC 3.1 application I'm trying to implement a **remember-me** feature (with info saved in the database).

Here's what I currently have :

- I created a [persistent_logins](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/remember-me.html#remember-me-persistent-token) table.
- I have this in my security context file :

  ```
  <form-login login-page="/login" 
          authentication-failure-url="/login?err=true"
          default-target-url="/" 
          username-parameter="username" 
          password-parameter="password"
          login-processing-url="/validatelogin" />

  <remember-me key="some_random_key" 
           token-validity-seconds="31536000" 
           data-source-ref="dataSource" />
  ```
- In my login.jsp, I have :

  ```
  <form action="/validatelogin" method="post">
      username : <input type='text' id='username' name='username' value='${SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_EXCEPTION.authentication.principal}' />
      <br />
      password : <input type='password' id='password' name='password' />
      <br /><br />
      remember me : <input type="checkbox" name="_spring_security_remember_me" />
      <br /><br />
      <input type="submit" value="submit" />
  </form>
  ```

In the "<form-login>" bean, I've been able to rename the default "j_password" and "j_username" fields that have to be used in the jsp, using *username-parameter* and *password-parameter*. But I don't find a way to rename the "_spring_security_remember_me" checkbox field.

Any idea on how to rename it?

Comment: My God how is this not a parameter on `<form-login>`??!!

Comment: Looks like `remember-me-parameter` has been added to the [latest version](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-security/blob/master/config/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/config/http/RememberMeBeanDefinitionParser.java)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That is set using the [`parameter`](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/rememberme/AbstractRememberMeServices.html#setParameter%28java.lang.String%29) property of `RememberMeServices`.

Sadly this isn't settable using the namespace config.   Here are a couple of ways you could set it:

1. Create a custom RememberMeServices and use it using `<remember-me services-ref="myRememberMeServices">`.   Set the property on your bean.
2. [Use a BeanPostProcessor (see 1.8)](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/faq.html#faq-namespace-post-processor) to set the property on the default `RememberMeServices`.

Comment: This is now possible to configure via the namespace starting with Spring Security 3.2.0.M2 - https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SEC-2119

Answer (score 3):

You should use BeanPostProcessor to set correct property:

Let's consider that you want to call your property "myRememberMeProperty"

Then your code should look like this:

```
public class MyBeanPostProcessor implements BeanPostProcessor {

 String myRememberMeProperty;


  public Object postProcessAfterInitialization(Object bean, String name) {
    if (bean instanceof AbstractRememberMeServices) {
      AbstractRememberMeServices rememberMe = (AbstractRememberMeServices) bean;
      rememberMe.setParameter(getMyRememberMeProperty());
    }
    return bean;
  }    
  public Object postProcessBeforeInitialization(Object bean, String name) {
    return bean;
  }

  public void setMyRememberMeProperty(String myRememberMeProperty){
    this.myRememberMeProperty = myRememberMeProperty;    

  }

 public String getMyRememberMeProperty(){
     return this.myRememberMeProperty;    

  }
}


<bean id="myBeanPostProcessor"
    class="x.y.z.MyBeanPostProcessor">
    <property name="myRememberMeProperty" value="myRememberMeProperty" />
</bean>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I accepted ericacm's answer, since I think it is more general. But In my particular case, using a BeanPostProcessor bean was the way to go and I used your example as is.. So thanks a lot! Note that I also changed the cookie name the same way, using setCookieName() on the AbstractRememberMeServices, from within my custom BeanPostProcessor!